# AppleScript display dialog that DOESN'T timeout

Tags: timeout, applescript

I want to get Mail to bounce its icon in the dock continually when I have new mail, until I go to Mail.  Unfortunately under El Capitan, it only seems to do it a couple of times per minute or so.

No problem, I thought, I'll make a rule to trigger a script which will tell it (Mail) to `display dialog`.

Working great, except that the dialog is timing out after 2 minutes, and so the dock icon stops bouncing :-(

I'm using `ignoring application responses` so the script terminates fine, I just want the dialog to ***not*** timeout!

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Normally OSAX commands never times out but since you have targeted `display dialog` to another application OSAX command do timeout. By default when you send an event to another application your script waits for an reply. When there is no reply from the other application within two minutes an timeout error will be returned. However there are events that can take longer than two minutes, so you can lengthen or shorten the wait time of your script before it returns an error.

```
tell application "Mail"
    with timeout of 300 seconds -- wait 5 minutes
        display dialog "hello world!"
    end timeout
end tell
```

Comment: I'd thought of that, but I don't want it to timeout at all.  If I happen to be away from my computer for say 10 hours, and then I look at the screen, I want to see the dock icon bouncing so I know I have mail.  Is there some way of changing the default behaviour ("By default [...] your script waits for a reply.  When there is no reply [...] a timeout error will be returned.")???

Comment: You can only set the timeout to an huge number. My example only shows five minutes, you can use 86400 to wait for a whole day.

Comment: OK, but that seems to conflict with `ignoring application responses`.  If I put the timeout outside `ignoring application responses` then the dialog still times out after 2 minutes.  If I put it inside, then the rest of the script doesn't get executed until the dialog times out.  Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Alternatively, is there some other way of getting applescript to bounce another app's dock icon continually?

Comment: Throwing and error would be the easiest and most ugly way I think. Why do you use `ignoring application responses` at all? They don't work with the display commands.

Comment: I've never used `ignoring application responses` before; the only reason I'm using it this time is that without it, Mail waits until the timeout before it updates the window.  I'm interested in your idea of throwing an error.  I've just tried it (`tell application "Mail" error -700 end tell`) and all that happens is a dialog box comes out saying -700.  Mail doesn't bounce.  Could you give me some pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that,

```
display dialog "Hello" giving up after 10
```